# OrientGraph Cannot Create A Connection To Remote Server Localhost:2424

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, orientdb, orientdb3.0, gremlin-java

## Problem

OrientGraph `Cannot create a connection to remote server localhost:2424` but OrientDB can.
Running [Apache-TinkerPop-3 Gremlin commands](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.2.x/tinkerpop3/OrientDB-TinkerPop3.html) through the [OrientDB API](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.2.x/gremlin/Gremlin.html), 
Either for [Java or Groovy](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Programming-Language-Bindings.html).

```js
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot create a connection to remote server address(es): [locahost:2424]
```

## [Reproduction Steps](https://orientdb.org/docs/3.2.x/fiveminute/)

1. Installed [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/orientdb)
2. Downloaded a [OrientDB Docker Image](https://orientdb.org/docs/3.2.x/admin/Docker-Home.html)
3. Started the [OrientDB Container](https://orientdb.org/docs/3.2.x/admin/installation/)
4. Created a [OrientDB Database "demodb"](https://orientdb.org/docs/3.2.x/fiveminute/java-1.html)
5. Verified [Setup / Running](https://orientdb.org/docs/3.2.x/fiveminute/java-4.html)
6. Created a [OrientGraph](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.2.x/gremlin/Gremlin.html)

   ```java
   OrientGraph graph = OrientGraph.open("remote:locahost:2424/demodb","root","rootpwd");
   ```
7. Ran the Program

```java
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseSession;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDB;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBConfig;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientGraph;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OrientDB orient = new OrientDB("remote:localhost:2424", OrientDBConfig.defaultConfig());
        ODatabaseSession db = orient.open("demodb", "root", "rootpwd");
        db.close();
        orient.close();

        OrientGraph graph = OrientGraph.open("remote:locahost:2424/demodb","root","rootpwd");
        graph.close();
    }
}
```

## Tried

1. Switching with default username/password: admin/admin
2. Changing port: `2424` to `2480` instead
3. Removing the database `localhost:2424/demodb` to `localhost:2424`
4. Checking [OrientDB Gremlin Maven package](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.orientechnologies/orientdb-gremlin/3.2.17)
5. Checking the [OrientDB's OrientGraph formatting](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.2.x/tinkerpop3/OrientDB-TinkerPop3.html#use-security)

## Results

```bash
INFO: - shutdown storage: demodb...
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot open database 'demodb'
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBRemote.open(OrientDBRemote.java:134)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDB.open(OrientDB.java:226)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDB.open(OrientDB.java:212)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientGraphFactory.getDatabase(OrientGraphFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientGraph.<init>(OrientGraph.java:167)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientGraph.open(OrientGraph.java:133)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.OrientGraph.open(OrientGraph.java:124)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot create a connection to remote server address(es): [locahost:2424]
    DB name="demodb"
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.openRemoteDatabase(OStorageRemote.java:1911)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.openRemoteDatabase(OStorageRemote.java:1755)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.open(OStorageRemote.java:618)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentRemote.internalOpen(ODatabaseDocumentRemote.java:247)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBRemote.open(OrientDBRemote.java:131)
    ... 7 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

### Expected

One of these to be what I was missing or misunderstood from the setup and documents.

### Actual

None of these changed the output Exception error.